# How can I make all of my buttons in a form to make its text to uppercase/lowercase?

Tags: c#, button, uppercase, lowercase

Is it possible to make all text of the buttons in my form uppercase/lowercase?

Comment: what do you mean by `button1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper`

Comment: @AlfredSanz, sorry i tot textboxes is the same as buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't done Win Form for a long time, but I suppose you can loop through all text contorls and set it at once.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls)
        if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            ((Button)ctrl).Text = ((Button)ctrl).Text.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: sorry sir i min buttons not textboxes

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Properties` and set the `CharacterCasing` into `Upper`., Just select all the `textBoxes`.
This is if you like to set the `CharacterCasing` when form is load.

Comment: sorry sir i min buttons :)

Answer (score 2):

some linq stuff :)

```
foreach(var btnobject in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
  //do stuff
   btnobject.Text=btnobject.Text.ToUpper();
}
```